# Operator norm of an identity map over $l_p$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$ ($p$ and $q$ are not related) conclude that the identity map I : $ l^n_p → l^n_q$ has operator norm exactly 1.

I figured I need to show that given $\|Ix\| \leq c\|x\|$ [from the wiki definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) the infimum over c is 1 so that $\|Ix\| = \|x\|$. is this a correct definition for the operator norm? and is it a good approach?

Can i apply [Riesz–Thorin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem) here? if so how?

Comment: What is the $l_p^n$ space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to show is that $\|Ix\|_q \le \|x\|_p$ for all $x \in \ell_p$ and that the ratio $\dfrac{\|Ix\|_q}{\|x\|_p}$ can be made arbitrarily close to $1$.

The second point is easy. If a sequence $x$ has exactly one nonzero term then $\|Ix\|_q = \|x\|_p$.

On the other hand if you write $\|x\|_\infty$ for the maximum of the terms of a sequence $x \in \ell_r$ then $$\|Ix\|_q^q = \sum_k |x_k|^q \le \|x\|_\infty^{q-p} \sum_k |x_k|^p = \|x\|_\infty^{q-p} \|x\|_p^p \le \|x\|_p^q.$$
Now take the $q$-root on both sides.

Comment: I understand why for a sequence with exactly one nonezero term $\|Tx\|_q=\|x\|p$ but how does it expands to include that the ratio $\frac{\|Ix\|_q}{\|x\|_p}$ can be made arbitrary  close to one for sequences   with more than one term?

Comment: The idea is that the supremum need only be attained (or approached) by *certain* elements of the space. To show show norm is $1$ doesn't require you to consider sequences with multiple nonzero terms.

Comment: How did you get $\vert \vert x \vert \vert _{\infty}^{q-p} \vert \vert x \vert \vert _{p}^{p} \leq \vert \vert x \vert \vert_{p}^{q}$?

Comment: @SABOY it follows from the fact that $\|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_p$, and $q-p > 0$.

Comment: Do we also have to show that $c=1$ is the smallest number such that $\| Ix \| \leq c\| x\|$?

Comment: @2pirsquared that is addressed in the second paragraph. No number $c < 1$ works with a sequence consisting of a single nonzero term.